# Select 1 record from each of 2 duplicate records

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a messaging application which regularly inserts duplicate messages in BigQuery. The table name is **'metrics'** and it has the following fields:

[image]

The **Row** column is a bigquery `ROW_NUMBER()` which is not part of the **metrics** table.  All the other columns except **batch_id** form 2 **duplicate** rows for each **message_id**. You can see that message_id is repeated twice, and for each insertion 1 different batch_id is created.

I want the output like this, only **3** rows should be in the select **result** with 3 different **message_id** instead of the 6 rows I get here. It would be better if the row which had been inserted first among the duplicates for each message id would be selected(as the **start_time** and **end_time** is same for the duplicates I am not sure how to find that).

I am new to Bigquery. I have seen some examples in SQL but not in Bigquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This deduping process becomes part of your business logic, so pick one method and stay consistent.  I would do something like this:

```
with data as (
  select 
  *,
  row_number() over(partition by message_id order by batch_id asc) as rn
  from `project.dataset.table`
)
select * from data where rn = 1
```

This query selects the row that has the "minimum" `batch_id` for each `message_id`.  Your `batch_id` seem random/hashed (and not necessarily in a specific order), so this might or might work for your purposes, but it should reproduce the same results everytime (unless a 3rd record shows up, then it could begin to vary).

Comment: Thanks,the bashid is a randomly generated string in python.  I was also getting sometimes 3 records  or more than 3 duplicates.The applicationinserts at the same time more than 2 records also, so will this work if that is case?

Comment: Generally yes, it will select only 1 record per `message_id`, if there is 1,2,3, etc. If you don't care which batch it comes from, then this is a reasonable solution.

Comment: Great Answer, Thanks, the rn is coming as 1,2 or 3 if there are 3 duplicate records, does that 1,2 or 3 indicates the order in which it was inserted, so If select rn=1 will it give the first inserted record or is there any way to get that first inserted record?

Comment: If you see the `rn` in the code, it is getting the first `batch_id` alphabetically.  You said it is random, so we cannot guarantee which one is 'first'. Unless you know the order of the batch_id (if they were somehow in order, or if there is an associated batch timestamp), then you will not be able to tell.  If they are dupes, and you have any info about the batch insert, then i'm not sure you would need to care.